# Encoding in message for SVN commit

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, encoding

I have a particular trouble with my commit messages in Intellij IDEA. My commit messages with non-English characters (in particular, Russians characters) after commit completing have wrong encoding. For example, I make commit and enter some Russain text as commit message. So far, so good. But when I do "checkout" for the same project from SVN (even on the same PC) I don't see my message, I see message in wrong encoding. Which settings in my IDE or on my PC are wrong?

By the way, I use windows-1251 encoding for all IDE settings:

[image]

and any other Russian text (e.g in .java files) is displayed normally.

Comment: What locale do you use on the this computer? Does the problem reproduce with TortoiseSVN?

Comment: @bahrep, My current language for non-Unicode programs (in Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region ->Administrative -> Language for non-Unicode programs) is Russian (Russia).

Comment: @bahrep, and yes, in TortoiseSVN logs I also see the same messages with wrong encoding.

Comment: BTW, was my answer helpful? Upvote then. ;) You can also click the tick sign to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not real solution, but some workaround... To copy the text from the Notepad++ file with UTF-8 encoding to the form for entering a comment to the commit in Intellij IDEA. After that, the commit comment is displayed correctly everywhere.

Hence, even if the project and the IDE encodings should be setted as *windows-1251*, commit comment in any case should have *UTF-8* encoding.

*P.S.* One of the possible reasons why this happens is the locale on the computer: *Language for non-Unicode programs* is *Russian (Russia)* now. But if I change this setting, it will affect quite a bit of files on the computer (for example, previously created in Notepad++ text files after changing the locale will become unreadable).

Answer (score 0):

The log message - maybe - got garbled in the commit process by a hook script. The problem may be caused by some commit hook script installed by the repository or server administrator. I would recommend that you contact an admin for assistance.

To double-check whether the repository actually contains garbled text or not, run the following command (REVNUM stands for revision number):

`svn propget svn:log --revprop -r REVNUM URL-TO-REPOSITORY > output.txt`

Then open output.txt file with notepad.exe or another text editor. If the Cyrillic text is garbled, you should definitely contact the admin.